# Bssh automate file transfer between two linux servers

Tags: linux, bash

Please, I am sorry to bother you with my questions but I have two question that i will like to have the input of an expert.

Question : 1

We have two linux based server that received incoming file from users and another server that we store those file in it I would like to know is there a way to automate the file transfer, let me explain myself here .

I want to know if it's possible for the file to be transferred to our asset server as soon as the user upload it and after that it should be deleted from the server.

Is there any method you can advise me to use I am new to Linux world but I have a programming background ,but was thinking about a bash but don't really know how to go about it.

Question 2 :

Is it possible to create a bash to automate file installation from online server.

Thank you your help will be appreciate.

Comment: Hi @semgmp, welcome to SO. It is expected from you to do a minimum of work before you ask any questions here. Have a look at http://www.mpipks-dresden.mpg.de/~mueller/docs/suse10.2/html/opensuse-manual_en/manual/sec.filetrans.copy.html Once you can do that, you can automate the whole process http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=233564

Answer (score 1):

I will give a generalised answer.

You could trigger a script on upload, or if that's not possible for some reason, then Linux has a couple of `notify` APIs that a command can use to `watch` a directory.

Once that's done, you will need to transfer the file.  Again, more than one way of doing this, but some possibilities would be `scp`, `sftp`, or an HTTP POST (maybe using `curl`).  If using `scp`/`sftp`, you should use key based authentication rather than passwords.

If, (and only if I presume) that worked successfully, you would want to remove the file (if it didn't, perhaps you could use the `mail` command to complain to someone and/or use the `mv` command to move the problem file into another directory).

If you wanted to use bash to automate some of this, then you should look at some of the following bash features:

- `&&` will execute the following command if the preceding command succeeded (returned with an exit code of 0)
- `||` will execute the following command if the preceding command failed (exit code != 0)
- `if then fi`
- `while do done`

Finally, on my system, the following command show some tools you might want to look into:

```
apt-cache search inotify
-
incron - cron-like daemon which handles filesystem events

inosync - notification-based directory synchronization daemon

inoticoming - trigger actions when files hit an incoming directory

inotify-hookable - blocking command-line interface to inotify

inotify-tools - command-line programs providing a simple interface to inotify

gamin - File and directory monitoring system

clsync - live sync tool based on inotify, written in GNU C

entr - Run arbitrary commands when files change

lsyncd - daemon to synchronize local directories using rsync

iwatch - realtime filesystem monitoring program using inotify
```

... one of those might just do everything you need out of the box...

Comment: Hi thank you very much for this answer is it possible for you to post an exemple of script that i might follow.

Answer (score 0):

the classic solution for your both question is bash script and `crontab`.
bash script will automate the file transfer and crontab will make it to be schedule when you like.

```
#!/bin/bash
scp -r /path/to/upload_files user@destination_IP:/path/to/upload/files
```

**in order to set cronjob:**

1. switch to required user run: `crontab -e`

Comment: Hi thank you very much i am doing some research on it but if you can post an example of script it can help